# Memory leak through new[] without ever calling new

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, new-operator, valgrind, fread

I'm getting a memory leak from the following function:

```
int ReadWrite(int socket, char *readfile) {
  FILE *rf = NULL;
  rf = fopen(readfile, "rb");
  fseek(rf, 0, SEEK_END);
  int len = ftell(rf);
  rewind(rf);

  char readbuf[len + 1];

  int res = fread(readbuf, len, 1, rf);
  readbuf[len + 1] = '\0';
  fclose(rf);
  while (1) {
    int wres = write(socket, readbuf, res);
    if (wres == 0) {
      cerr << "socket closed prematurely" << endl;
      close(socket);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (res == -1) {
      if (errno == EINTR)
        continue;
      cerr << "socket write failure: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
      close(socket);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    break;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Valgrind tells me I leak the number of bytes that are in readfile (the actual file, not the name of readfile) through this operation:

```
Address 0x4c3b67e is 0 bytes after a block of size 14 alloc'd
at 0x4A07C84: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:363)
```

What's confusing me is I don't ever use new[] in my code. I checked fopen, ftell, and fread to see if they have hidden "gotcha's" where they call new[] somewhere but didn't find anything in the documentation on cplusplus.com. I've tried all different combinations of new char[]/delete[], malloc/free, and stack-allocated variables (above) but I get the same valgrind message every time. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `char readbuf[len + 1];` is invalid C++.

Comment: This is a very strange code: 'char readbuf[len + 1]'. What compiler do you use?

Comment: You should probably change `readbuf[len + 1] = '\0';` to `readbuf[len] = '\0';`, unless you are purposely trying to overrun readbuf. Also, are you really using C99, rather than C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem actually had to do with the Makefile I was using. Thanks for the insight on my slip-up with the char[] bounds though!

Comment: Can you explain what was the problem with the Makefile? Thanks.

Comment: I unfortunately don't remember the specific reason the Makefile was causing issues. But I do remember it was because I had a misunderstanding on how Makefiles work. Sorry I don't have more for you - the best I can do is point you to a tutorial on Makefiles (http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html). Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 7):

you call

- `char readbuf[len + 1];`

  and then later
- `readbuf[len + 1] = '\0';`

wouldn't that overflow the array?

Comment: Not to mention that `char readbuf[len + 1]` isn't valid C++ since `len` isn't `const`.

Comment: @NikBougalis: That's nonstandard still, but (A) GCC has allowed it for a while, and (B) they're working on standardizing it.

Comment: @MooingDuck gcc may support this, in which case, the gcc manual should explain how the memory ought to be freed (update: it's freed automatically by the compiler per the [docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)), but it's not standard today so the code isn't valid C++. It's a valid "gcc-extended C++" but that's not the same thing as "C++".

Comment: Yeah, it should automatically be freed.  I don't know where the error is coming from

Comment: I changed both to readbuf[len] but that didn't fix anything. How would that overflow the array? Also, I'm using g++ as my compiler.

Comment: I suspect the error is coming from a confused `valgrind` which doesn't understand the semantics of the gcc allocation operation.

Comment: I found out the problem actually had to do with the Makefile I was using. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @PoseidonOnline: It overflows the buffer because a `char[]` holds the number of characters you provide it, but they are indexed from `0` to `n-1` where `n` is the value you declared it with. You're trying to write to one past the final key because the final character's index is `len`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are declaring your `readbuf` array with non-constant size (i.e with run-time size). This is formally illegal in C++. Such feature exists in C99, but not in C++. Your code will not even compile in a pedantic C++ compiler. And your question is tagged [C++].

But it is quite possible that your compiler implements this feature as a non-standard extension, and that it creates such arrays through an implicit call to `new[]`. This is why you get the error message that refers to `new[]`, even though you are not using `new[]` explicitly.

Of course, it is the compiler's responsibility to deallocate such arrays when they end their lifetime. I suspect that the compiler does all it has to do, but the `valgrind` is confused by something in compiler's actions, which makes it conclude that it is a memory leak.

Moreover, as others already noted, you are making out of bounds access to your array, which can also lead to absolutely any problems at run-time, including the strange report from `valgrind`.